# Create Bootable in Mac to use in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, 20.04, live-usb, boot-repair

I have a Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 already installed.

I don't know what happened, but the system is not workin anymore, everytime I start the computer the error message: "Error loading the operation system" appears and I can not advanced more from here.

If I press F10 I arrive to the GRUB, but I do not know what to do with it.

My question is: I want to restart my Ubuntu laptop with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.

I have another MAC computer, and I was thinking in creating a bootable in my MAC but to use this bootable in the UBUNTU LAPTOP.

For now, all the examples that I have seen to create bootables in MAC, are for using this bootable with the MAC itself, and I do not want this. I want to create the bootable in the MAC and use it in the Ubuntu machine.

I think creating the bootable could work to restart my system, but if there is an easy way, I will appreciated it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview

Comment: I already used that one, thanks. But it seems that the usb stick is for using with Mac. I don't know if it has something to do with the disk format MS-DOS (FAT). Or if just my Ubuntu it's not detecting the bootable stick.